# how to select last row values of particular column sql android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i am beginner in android i am not getting the concept where am i wrong,what are my mistakes.

i am trying to get last edited message from user or last saved message
and when user click on send button it need to go to particular whats app number with current location of the user

my data base name is mydb and my table name is Mytable
i have two column first is id auto increment and second column msg

but when i run my code this gives me output as below

//MY OUTPUT IS //

```
EMERGENCY

null

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=12.88758733,74.83737172
```

i am getting the null value instead of last message saved.
please guide me, i am in new in android

thankyou

```
//MY MAIN ACTIVITY//   
package com.myproject.harjinder_singh_lohia_bobby.harjicateringapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  SQLiteDatabase db;
  String ms,msgg;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Mytable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,msg VARCHAR(100));");
}
public void onclicksavemsg(View view)
{
    EditText tempmsg =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etmsg);
    String name=tempmsg.getText().toString();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Mytable(msg)VALUES('"+name+"');");
    TextView tv=findViewById(R.id.tvv);
    Cursor last_msg = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE id = '"+db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable",null)+"'",null);
    if(last_msg.moveToLast())
    {
        msgg=last_msg.getString(1);
    }
    tv.setText(msgg);
}

public void send(View view)
{
    GPStracker g = new GPStracker(getApplicationContext());
    Location l = g.getLocation();
    if (l != null) {
        double lat = l.getLatitude();
        double lon = l.getLongitude();
        String message = "\nhttp://maps.go"+"ogle.com/maps?saddr=" + lat + "," + lon;

        //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Mytable ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1";
       Cursor last_msg = db.rawQuery("SELECT msg FROM Mytable WHERE id = '"+db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable",null)+"'",null);
        if(last_msg.moveToLast())
       {
           ms=last_msg.getString(0);

       }
        String num = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + num + "&text="+"\nEMERGENCY\n"+ms;
        sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url+message));
        if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

}

//I WANT MY OUTPUT TO BE LIKE

```
EMERGENCY

SAVE ME I AM IN DANGER HELP ME

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=12.88758733,74.83737172
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the same mistake twice in your code:

```
Cursor last_msg = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE id = '"+db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable",null)+"'",null);
```

You can't add the result of 2 `rawQuery()` methods (meaning add 2 `Cursor` objects). 
 Change the 1st statement like this:

```
Cursor last_msg = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable)", null);
```

and the 2nd to:

```
Cursor last_msg = db.rawQuery("SELECT msg FROM Mytable WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable)", null);
```

Comment: this is the great help u have done forpas ... i was strugling fm so many days ... and finnaly i was trying to do new question and i just saw yrs today and this is great help done by u... thank you so much brother love u brother

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this raw-query,

```
select max(id) as id from your_table_name
```

Since you are getting only one value from your query, you dont need to call,

```
if(last_msg.moveToLast())  
 { msgg=last_msg.getString(1);   
}   
tv.setText(msgg);
```

Just use ,

```
cursor.movetoposition(0);  
    msgg=cursor.getString(1);
    tv.setText(msgg);
```

Comment: this gives me out of index error , brother can how to overcome error?

Comment: Put it in if loop of cursor.getCount()>0 with log and debug .

Comment: It is not working at all, i mean no reaction, when i click no responce, what is my mistake??